# how to resolve this sql question without using window function

Tags: sql, postgresql

DDL:

```
create table domain_lifecycle (
domain varchar,
timestamp timestamp,
lifecycle varchar);
```

DML:

```
insert into domain_lifecycle values
('example_1.com', '2020-01-01 01:01:00', 'start'),
('example_1.com', '2020-01-01 01:01:05', 'end'),
('example_2.com', '2020-01-01 01:01:07', 'start'),
('example_2.com', '2020-01-01 01:01:17', 'end'),
('example_3.com', '2020-01-01 01:01:20', 'start'),
('example_1.com', '2020-01-01 01:01:25', 'start'),
('example_3.com', '2020-01-01 01:01:23', 'end'),
('example_1.com', '2020-01-01 01:01:38', 'end'),
('example_3.com', '2020-01-01 01:01:40', 'start'),
('example_3.com', '2020-01-01 01:01:42', 'end');
```

Question: find the domains whose any of the lifecycles (the time elapsed between lifecycle start and end) is at least 5 seconds.

I know how to use window function (lag()) to resolve this:

```
select distinct domain from
(select *, 
       lag(timestamp) over(partition by domain order by timestamp) as pre_timestamp 
from domain_lifecycle) t
where lifecycle = 'end'
  and extract(epoch from (timestamp - pre_timestamp)) >= 5;
```

expected result:

[image]

How can we resolve this question without using window function? Thanks.

**Update**:
I updated the above DML by adding one more lifecycle(the last two rows) for domain `example_3.com` to make it clear that the `5 seconds` criterion only applies to the same lifecycle that has adjacent `start` and `end` for the same domain (it could be separated by other domains' lifecycle though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT domain
FROM domain_lifecycle dlc
WHERE dlc.lifecycle = 'start'
AND EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
     FROM
       (SELECT MIN(TIMESTAMP) "end_time"
        FROM domain_lifecycle dlc2
        WHERE dlc.domain = dlc2.domain
          AND dlc2.timestamp > dlc.timestamp
          AND dlc2.lifecycle = 'end'
        ) t
     WHERE extract(epoch from t.end_time - dlc.timestamp) >= 5
    );
```

[Demo db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=986515043f0541107be5ef0b40e2e6ab)

Answer (score 1):

One alternative method is to use a lateral join to select the next end for each start.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       domain
       FROM domain_lifecycle c1
            CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT min(timestamp) "timestamp"
                                       FROM domain_lifecycle c2
                                       WHERE c2.domain = c1.domain
                                             AND c2.lifecycle = 'end'
                                             AND c2.timestamp >= c1.timestamp) c3
       WHERE c1.lifecycle = 'start'
             AND c3.timestamp - c1.timestamp >= '5 seconds'::interval;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=f4e84f51048894941791b419c0809728)

Answer (score 0):

Your `lag()` is getting `domains` where the "end" lifecycle is 5 or more seconds after the previous lifecycle.

The simplest method to replace your specific query is probably `exists`:

```
select distinct dl.domain
from domain_lifecycle dl
where dl.lifecycle = 'end' and
      exists (select 1
              from domain_lifecycle dl2
              where dl2.domain = dl.domain and
                    dl2.timestamp < dl.timestamp and
                    extract(epoch from (dl.timestamp - dl2.timestamp)) >= 5
             );
```

However, your data and explanation suggest a simpler approach -- aggregation and `having`:

```
select dl.domain
from domain_lifecycle dl
group by dl.domain
having extract(epoch from (max(dl.timestamp) - min(dl.timestamp))) >= 5;
```

Or as I prefer to write it:

```
select dl.domain
from domain_lifecycle dl
group by dl.domain
having max(dl.timestamp) >= min(dl.timestamp) + interval '5 second';
```

If you can have lifecycles values other than `'start'` and `'end', then you can add a filter to these queries to focus on these two values (this is true of the query in your question as well).

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8e52a597052ee357853b20b1d0df133d) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

Your actual question can be rephrased as:  Does a `domain` have any "end"s with no "start" in the preceding five seconds.  This can be solved using:

```
select distinct dl.domain
from domain_lifecycle dl
where dl.lifecycle = 'end' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from domain_lifecycle dl2
                  where dl2.domain = dl.domain and
                        dl2.lifecycle = 'start' and
                        dl2.timestamp < dl.timestamp and
                        dl2.timestamp >= dl.timestamp - interval '5 second
                 );
```

This can use an index on `(domain, lifecycle, timestamp)`.  Because there is no aggregation and the time range is limited, this might have the best performance profile.  That said, window functions are better suited to this problem.

Comment: each domain could have multiple lifecycles defined between `start` and `end`, the 5 seconds criterion only applies to the same lifecycle which has adjacent `start` and `end` for this domain but that could be separated by other domains' lifecycles. So we can't just use `max(dl1.timestamp) - min(dl2.timestamp) >=  '5 second':: interval`; rather, these timestamps have to be in the same lifecycle of this domain.

Comment: I updated the DML with one more test case to make this clear.

Comment: Window functions are your best bet. Why don't you want to use them?

Comment: we have some old servers with some old version postgresql which may not support window function. But if this is the best bet we probably have to go with this.